# Simulate a strange distribution in R

Tags: r, histogram, simulation

Hi all I'm attempting to simulate data that looks something like this: [image]

Anyone know how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: Do you know what that lowest bin should look like?  Are they all exactly zero, or spread out in the bin?

Comment: We have now three different answers, so it would be interesting to see what the OP knows about the distribution. I guess there are no parameters available for a mixture yet? The question is then whether (1) **empirical data are known** or (2) if the task is just to create a **similar qualitative pattern** by trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

This can be considered as a classical problem to transform uniform random numbers generated with `runif` with an inverse transformation from empirical relative frequencies. Here an approach that uses approx:

```r
freq <- c(0.39, 0.02, 0.15, 0.18, 0.12, 0.09,0.04, 0.01)
sum(freq) # This is a check. The sum must be 1.0.

r_empirical <- function(n, freq) {
  approx(c(0, cumsum(freq)), 0:(length(freq)),
         runif(n), method="constant", f=0)$y
}

x <- r_empirical(1000, freq)

hist(x, breaks=0:length(freq))
```

[image: generated distrigbution]

The following figure demonstrates the basic principle. The stairs show the cumulative distribution, the red arrows how a uniform random number can be transformed:

[image: inverse transform]

Comment: I suppose `sample(0:(length(freq)-1), n, prob=freq, TRUE)` would work for this example, but less interesting.

Comment: @user20650: agreed, this works indeed in the discrete case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use two beta distributions.

Beta is a very useful distribution.

```
beta<-c(rbeta(600, 0.1, 5, ncp = 0),rbeta(1200, 3, 4, ncp = 1))

hist(beta,breaks=30,probability = T)
```

[image: betadist]

Comment: One can also use other mixtures, e.g. an exponential and a normal. But then the problem arises how to estimate the parameters. This is of course possible (see [here](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/antibioticR/articles/Introduction.html)), but the next question is then to derive the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Zero-inflated log-Normal? (Spike at zero looks a little too big for a Tobit, i.e. censored Normal with the negative stuff piled up on zero)

```r
zero_prob <- 0.25
meanlog <- log(20)
sdlog <- 0.4 ## SD ~ 40%

n <- 500
rzilnorm <- function(n, pz, meanlog, sdlog) {
   ifelse(runif(n) < pz, 0,
          rlnorm(n, meanlog, sdlog))
}
set.seed(101)
hist(rzilnorm(n=500, zero_prob, meanlog, sdlog), col = "gray", breaks=25, freq=FALSE)
```

[image: histogram]

My first try was with `n=100` and `pz=0.2`; if I were going to play around with this more I might increase `sdlog` a little bit. Otherwise this looks pretty close?